# How to retrieve cvPoint values for further Processing?

Tags: opencv

This is the function to draw rectangle with providing respective values for parameters

```
void rectangle(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2,const Scalar& color, int thickness=1,int lineType=8, int shift=0);
```

Users can use this function to set ROI with mouse , to draw rectangle on detected matches in Templte Matching application.
My Question is , 2nd and 3rd parameters are Points here. If user want to get point 1 nd point 2 values for further processing , How to get that ?! How to print the both point values?! Point to double or int conversion ?!

Anyone ,clear my doubts. Thanks in advance for help !!

Updated:

```
void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)

{

if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
{
    /* left button clicked. ROI selection begins */
    point1 = Point(x,y);
    drag = 1;

}

if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
{
    /* mouse dragged. ROI being selected */
    Mat img1 = mod_tempimg.clone();
    point2 = Point(x, y);
    rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    imshow("image", img1);

}

if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
{

    Mat img2=mod_tempimg.clone();
    point2 = Point(x, y);
rect = Rect(point1.x,point1.y,x-point1.x,y-point1.y);
     drag = 0;
     roiImg = mod_tempimg(rect1);
    imshow("image", img2);
}

if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
{
   /* ROI selected */
    select_flag = 1;
    drag = 0;
}
```

In  the above code ,
How to retrieve Point values from this line?!

```
  rect = Rect(point1.x,point1.y,x-point1.x,y-point1.y);
```

If I know the values that will helpful to find the angle of rect .

Comment: Please post what you have with the rectangle so far. I use opencv in python but could probably figure out what you need if you post more clearly what doesn't work in code.

Comment: Are you asking for how to calculate the corners of that rectangle? The corners are point1 and point2.You said "line" but there is no explicit "line" in the code. What did you mean by "line"? Also, what does "angle of the rect" mean?

Comment: @kobajohn ... here the line I have indicated in my question is just the line of code (eg: line no :1). Not about line in opencv . So, after drawing rectangle in source image I want to get the four corner point values . When I m trying to convert Point to Int or double values ,I am getting error like USER CONVERSIONS NOT POSSIBLE. help me in this regard. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

even after update, the question is not clear to me. I am not sure what exactly you are asking. 
Anyways, as far I understand, you are creating a rectangle object here:

```
rect = Rect(point1.x,point1.y,x-point1.x,y-point1.y);
```

and you want to get the corner points of rect later.

`rect.tl()` gives the top left corner point and  `rect.br()` gives the bottom right corner point. You can also get the x and y values of a corner by : `rect.tl().x or rect.br().y`

I do not know what you mean by "find angle of rect". Rectangles have 90 degree angles.

Comment: your answer gave some idea about how tyo find corner points but when I m trying to convert Point values to int or double I am getting errorlike user conversions not possible.And " Find angle of rect" means I am trying to find the angle of rectangle with two corner values .If I know two corner values(point values in Int or Double)than I will calculate angle with formula (angle=atan2(x2-x1,y2-y1)). help me in this regard.Thank you!!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, rect.tl() is top left point. rect.br() is bottom right point. They are of type cv::Point or cv:Point2f etc.
You can always get the x and y values from a Point type in OPneCv.
e.g . : rect.tl().x, rect.tl().y, rect.br().x, rect.br().y. If your rect.tl() is of type Point then rect.tl().x and rect.tl().y are of type int. If your rect.tl() is of type Point2f then rect.tl().x and rect.tl().y are of type float. I hope now you get your x1,x2,y1,y2. Do wahtever with them as you wish.

Answer (score 5):

when you are writing the program for drawing rectangle with 2 points, you have the points in hand.

Print the point: `cout << pt1`

Print x value and y value of the point : `cout << pt1.x << pt1.y`

assign x value explicitly : `pt1.x = 0`

Get the pixel intensity at some point : `image.at<uchar>( pt1)`  [ for grayscale image]